# What is the value of this expectation?

Tags: conditional-expectation, expected-value

I have a conditional expectation question: how to calculate this expectation?

$$E[X-E(X|Y)|Y]$$

Comment: Just put in your probability distribution function and integrate.

Comment: Are you familiar with the law of iterated expectation? Can you pull some terms out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional expectations are linear:
$$E[X-E(X|Y)|Y]=E[X|Y]-E[E(X|Y)|Y]$$
By the tower property (requiring that the sigma algebra of the outer expectation is in the sigma algebra of the inner expectation).
$$E[X|Y]-E[E(X|Y)|Y]=E[X|Y]-E[X|Y]=0$$

Comment: Or one can use, that $E(X|Y)$ is $Y$-measurable, hence $E[E(X|Y)|Y] = E(X|Y)$.

Comment: @typewriter Thanks for the explanation but how to prove that conditional expectations are linear?

Comment: There are multiple definitions of conditional expectation. E(X|Y) can be defined as a function such that for any measurable $f$ we have:
$$\int E(X|Y) f(Y) dP = \int X f(Y) dP.$$
From the linearity of the integral we find:
$$\int E(X_1+X+2|Y)f(Y) = \int (X_1+X_2) f(Y) dP = \int X_1 f(Y)dP +\int X_2 f(Y)dP = \int (E(X_1|Y)+E(X_2|Y)) f(Y) dP$$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$E\bigg(E(X|Y)|Y\bigg)=E(g(Y)|Y)=g(Y)=E(X|Y)$$